# Exporting data to Excel according to checked Item

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

I am writing a Windows Forms application and I have a checkListBox connected to my SQL database. I have everything else working but exporting some data to an Excel file. I have successfully created my Excel and my column and everything. I am able to export the checked item to my Excel.

This is my header:

```
 Teacher Id      Last Name     First Name      NickName      Salary
```

In my check list box, it displayed a list of NickName so when I selected two out of three nickname in my checkListBox, it will display the nickname of what I selected from the check list box to the nickname column in my Excel file. For example, if I select name Circle and Apple, my **Excel file** will display something like this below

**(Table 1)**

```
  Teacher Id      Last Name     First Name      NickName      Salary                                                     
                                                 Apple
                                                 Circle
```

This part works fine and is what I have in my code below so far. However, what I really want is also to display the first name and the last name from my database table according to what I have checked. So far I am not sure how to do that.

For example, this is my **database** table call teacher_detail and it has something like this:

**Database Table:**

```
   teacherId     lastName     firstName    nickName    salary    emailAddress    
     1              Chan         Peter       Circle      10000      som@dsd.com         
     2              Trump        Donald      Apple       20000      sods@dfsd
     3              Gate         Bill        Gen         30000      see@sds.com
```

So if I select some checkbox from my checklistBox and export it to my Excel file, it will have something like this: (this is my **Excel** file):

**Desired Excel Table**

```
 Teacher Id      Last Name     First Name      NickName      Salary

    1              Chan         Peter           Circle
    2              Trump        Donald          Apple
```

This is my code and will show (Table 1) that I showed above:

```
   private void exportToExcel(){
     object missing = Type.Missing;

                myConn = new SqlConnection("Server = localhost; Initial Catalog= dbName; Trusted_Connection = True");
                try
                {

                    myConn.Open();

                    int index = applicationComboBox.SelectedIndex;
                    string query = " SELECT * FROM [Teacher_Detail];
                    myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConn);

                    SqlDataReader dr = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    //Reading all the value one by one 

                    Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();



                    xlApp.Visible = false;

                    Excel.Workbook xlwb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(missing);

                    //Workbook name is whatever the application name is 
                    string WbName = this.applicationComboBox.GetItemText(this.applicationComboBox.SelectedItem);

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(WbName);

                    sb.Replace("/", "or");
                    sb.Replace("-", "");
                    sb.Replace(",", "");

                    //first worksheet
                    Excel.Worksheet xlTeacherDetail = xlwb.ActiveSheet as Excel.Worksheet;

                    xlTeacherDetail.Name = "Teachers Detail";

                    //Cell name 
                    xlTeacherDetail.Cells[1, 1] = "Teacher Id";
                    xlTeacherDetail.Cells[1, 2] = "First Name";
                    xlTeacherDetail.Cells[1, 3] = "Last Name";
                    xlTeacherDetail.Cells[1, 4] = "Nick Name";
                    xlTeacherDetail.Cells[1, 5] = "Salary";
                    xlTeacherDetail.Cells[1, 6] = "Email";

                    //Iterate through each check box in teacher check list box to see which one is checked

                    **This is where I have problem with**
                    for (int i = 0; i < teacherCheckListBox.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (teacherCheckListBox.GetItemChecked(i))
                        {
                            string str = (string)teacherCheckListBox.Items[i];
                            //This code display what is show (Table 1)
                            xlTeacherDetail.Cells[2 + i, 4] = str;


                            //Start to read my data base table here


                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        string l_Name = dr.GetString(5);
                        string f_Name = dr.GetString(6);


                        xlTeacherDetail.Cells[2 + i, 3] = l_Name;
                        xlTeacherDetail.Cells[2 + i, 2] = f_Name;
                    }
                        }
                    }  **//To Here** 

            saveDig.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
                    saveDig.FileName = sb.ToString();
                    saveDig.Filter = "Excel fiels (*.xls) |*.xls";
                    saveDig.FilterIndex = 0;
                    saveDig.RestoreDirectory = true;
                    saveDig.Title = "Export Excel File To";
        }
}
```

What This code show:

```
 Teacher Id      Last Name     First Name      NickName      Salary

                  Chan         Peter           Circle
                                                Apple
```

Comment: Not sure but shouldn't `xlTeacherDetail.Cells[2 + 1, 3] = l_Name` read `xlTeacherDetail.Cells[2 + i, 3] = l_Name`.  NB change from 1 to i

Comment: @RobCorll, This part will only display one `l_name` and `f_name` in my excel, even if I have two NickName. Itcouldn't show 2 l_Name and f_Name when I have 2 nick names in my excel file .

Answer (score 0):

I got this working, I misplaced my while loop. It should be

```
 while (dr.Read())
            {
                //Iterate through each check box in teacher check list box to see which one is checked
                for (int i = 0; i < teacherCheckListBox.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (teacherCheckListBox.GetItemChecked(i))
                {
                    string str = (string)teacherCheckListBox.Items[i];


                        string l_Name = dr.GetString(5);
                        string f_Name = dr.GetString(6);

                        xlTeacherDetail.Cells[2 + i, 2] = f_Name;
                        xlTeacherDetail.Cells[2 + i, 3] = l_Name;
                        xlTeacherDetail.Cells[2 + i, 4] = str;



                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class called `Teacher`, read the data from your SqlDataReader creating a list of Teachers, `List<Teacher>`.
Then as you loop through your CheckedListBox, find the matching Teacher in the list and write the values to your `xlTeacherDetail`.

A better approach, assuming the query was already called before populating the CheckedListBox is to build the List then and add each Teacher object to the CheckListBoxItem.Tag property

```
teacherCheckListBox.Items.Add(new CheckListBoxItem()
    {
        Tag = teacher,
        Text = teacher.Name
    });
```

Then you can cast the Tag to type Teacher to retrieve the information without having to make the second SQL call.